# What are the ways to seed DB

Tags: java, sql, database

I want to seed my DB with some data. What are the ways to achieve it. I have seen some people running sql scripts in java to seed. Why don't they run those scripts directly on DB platform.

Comment: I don't have any best practices but I can just tell you about the last two applications I worked on.  They both had separate "repository" projects that built the database schema and populated tables with initial data (i.e. lookup tables, sample data).  The install can be scripted in whatever language you want to use -- my last project I used python to run the repository install scripts.

Comment: You can use a tool such as [Liquibase or Flyway](https://medium.com/@ruxijitianu/database-version-control-liquibase-versus-flyway-9872d43ee5a4).